# Can't boot into Windows after removing Linux

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, multi-boot, bootloader

I had Linux Ubuntu and Windows dual booting from my computer.  I used Gparted to remove the Linux Ubuntu partitions, now I can't get into Windows.

I think it's got something to do with the Linux BootLoader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't restored the MBR, then that is probably the cause.  There is a complete guide to the whole process at "[How To Safely Uninstall Ubuntu From A Dual Boot](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/)"

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses GRUB - a chained bootloader which is alos outside 512 bytes of MBR. You choose to install grub on MBR instead of default choice - 1st sector of partition.
FreeBSD has bootloader which lets choose boot partitions easily (in 1 sector)